# Why does my train loss jump down when a new epoch starts?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, classification, sampling, loss

When I train a neural network consisting of 2 convolutional and 2 fully connected layers on the MNIST handwritten digits task, I receive the following train loss curve:

[image]

The datasets contains 235 batches and I plotted the loss after each batch for 1500 batches in total, and trained therefore the model for a little more than 6 epochs. The batches are sampled using the following PyTorch code:

```
            sampler = torch.utils.data.RandomSampler(train_dataset, replacement=False)
            train_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, sampler=sampler)
```

So, in each epoch every batch is looked at once and every epoch has a new shuffling of the batches. As you see in the plot, the loss decreases at every start of the epoch rapidly.
I have never seen this behavior before and I was wondering why that is the case.

For comparison, when I run the same code, but I choose to sample with replacement, I get the following (normal looking) loss curve:

[image]

My thoughts so far:
Since at the start of each epoch the specific samples are already looked at before, the network could have an easier task if it memorized the specific batches. Still, since at every epoch there is a different shuffling, the network would have to memorize all batches which in my experience does not happen after 2 epochs.

I have also tried it on another dataset and with a variation of the model with the same results.

My model structure is the following:

```
self.conv_part = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(1, 32, (5, 5), stride=1, padding=2),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d((2, 2)),
            nn.Conv2d(32, 64, (5, 5), stride=1, padding=2),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d((2, 2))
        )
        self.linear_part = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(7*7*64, 1024),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(1024, 10)
        )
```

When the model is simplified by reducing the number of channels in each layer significantly, the problem vanishes almost completely, I have marked the epochs to get a clearer view.

[image]

Comment: Are you plotting the loss itself or doing some smoothing (i.e. a running average)?

Comment: Also, is each batch identical across "epochs" or do you shuffle the examples within each batch as well after each epoch?

Comment: I am plotting the average and the standard error of 20 runs with different shuffling seeds, thats why one can see the shaded areas above and below the graph.

Comment: The batches are not identical across epochs, they get sampled newly in every epoch.

Comment: Did you figure out why this happens? I have a very similar problem right now. I found that the Adam optimizer can cause this sort of periodic patterns (http://www.satyenkale.com/papers/amsgrad.pdf) but in my case, using both using amsgrad or reducing the learning rate don't change the pattern. I'm getting this accross a wide range of graph neural network architectures.

Comment: After discussing with a friend, our hypothesis is about overfitting. At the beginning of an epoch, the model overfits quickly to some first examples. Thus, the subsequent examples within that epoch would have larger loss values. In the next epoch, the model re-visit those examples, and because of its overfitting, the loss is lower than the one in the previous epoch.

Comment: Could you repeat the experiments with a flag `drop_last=True` added to the `DataLoader`?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in a comment, this figure can be indicating an overfitting problem. When a model is overfitting, each training iteration only decreases the loss for the batch that it's currently training on and not the next batches. That's why you don't see a decrease in loss during an epoch. However, during the next epoch, the model has lower losses for all of the samples, simply because it has "memorized" the samples from the previous epoch.

In other words, in a scenario where the model doesn't overfit, it learns some useful features from the current batch that it then can use on the next batch that it encounters. Otherwise, it's just memorizing the labels for the samples without finding more useful features.

Comment: That's a hypothesis, which may not necessarily be true.

Comment: You're absolutely right. It's no proof that the only way we see this plot is overfitting. But that's the only explanation I could think of. Do you have any ideas what else can cause this behavior?

Comment: Sure, I added my humble hypothesis as an answer too.

Answer (score 0):

Given that MNIST has 60k samples and you had 235 batches we conclude that:

- batch size is 256,
- there were 234 batches of 256  samples,
- final batch of size 96 samples.

One probable hypothesis is that when using `no-replacements` sampling, the smaller last batch causes higher gradient (because it averages over smaller number of samples) and allows model to jump to a new area in the parameter spaces. It's like a one-time regularization shot. After such a jump, for a few iterations the loss goes quickly down but then starts to overfit in the new area.

This is for `no-replacements` sampling. For sampling with replacement I guess that the last batch is sampled to the full size of 256 so the above effect does not take place.

Keep in mind that this is just a hypothesis. To test it: add `drop_last=True` to the `DataLoader` and repeat the `no-replacements` experiment. (BTW, I would really like to know what was the motivation to set drop_last to False by default - I think it's a unfortunate decision on pytorch side).

An alternative test would be to use batch size that divides number of samples exactly, for example 200 instead of 256.

I am really curious to see the result :)